# Conformal mapping from $\{|z| < 1\} \backslash [0, 1)$ to upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

Find an explicit conformal mapping from the region
\begin{equation}
        \{|z| < 1\} \backslash [0, 1)
    \end{equation}

onto the upper half plane $\{Im z> 0\}$

I know that the maps $F(z) = \frac{i - z}{i+z}$ and $G(z) = i\frac{1 - z}{1+z}$ map the unit disc to the upper half plane. However, in the case when the disk has a segment removed I'm not sure how to modify these mamps to give a conformal mapping.

Comment: It will not be enough to use only linear fractional transformations like your $F,G$.  Do you know some other analytic functions to use?

Comment: Inversion $F(z) = 1/z$ comes to mind but this maps the lower half of the disk to the negative half plane

Comment: For a google search use the word "slit" e.g., "unit disk with a slit on real positive axis" gives [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3108117/305862).